# Strange behavior of Bootstrap 3x in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web made with Bootstrap 3.3.5 and im using col-md-6 to display 2 responsive columns inside a container-fluid, the problem is that the padding in Chrome + Firefox is correct but not for IE11, the scrolling bar of IE11 seems to eat some of the padding.

There is any solution for this or i need to made de col-md-6 15px to 30px in order to view the web right in IE11?

[image: Layout in Chrome]

[image: Layou in IE11]

Thanks in advance for your attention :)

Comment: Please copy your `HTML` and `CSS` here.

Comment: Indeed is duplicate :) thanks for the link!

Adding -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar; in my css custom file fix the problem!

body {
  background:#eeeeee !important;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}